# Disable https for a single file in apache

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, apache-2.4, https, web-hosting

For a long time, I didn't use https on my linux server because I didn't find a decent CA that suits my needs. Now, Let's Encrypt (a new CA that provides free certificates) has launched their open beta so I got a certificate from them right away.

I am now redirecting all requests to https and everything works fine so far but since I have used http for ages, I will need some time to rewrite some client software that depends on the wbesite being http. Unfortunately I cannot deploy the update right away since the update mechanism is now broken too :/

So my question is: Is there a way to disable https for one single file in apache2? I'd prefer a solution using a simple .htaccess file but anything else is appreciated as well.

This was added to the VirtualHost ***:80** by letsencrypt:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your default vhost, try the following:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/your_single_file.html$
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=permanent]
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately I couldn't get on my computer earlier.  
However, I do have a question about the path. Since it seems to be an absolute path, does it start at the apache document root or the file system root? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a `REQUEST_URI`, (that is: the path written by the user in the url bar), so it has to be the apache doument root